# What does ▲ mean in a newspaper?

Tags: punctuation

I was reading [this article](https://mainichi.jp/articles/20200131/ddm/001/070/090000c) and noticed it had some ▲ symbols.

「われわれは欧州合衆国とでもいうべきものを成立させねばならない。その最初の一歩、欧州評議会創設の緊急事業を成功させるためにフランスとドイツは協働しなければならない」。はて、誰の発言か▲実はこれ、根っからの保守主義者でナショナリストだった英国のチャーチルの言葉である。１９４６年、チューリヒでの演説で、２度の大戦で荒廃し米ソに分断された欧州の文明の再興を、政治家なら誰もが真剣に考えた時代だった▲時は流れ、欧州２８カ国が加盟した今日の欧州連合（ＥＵ）からいよいよ英国がきょう（日本時間あす朝）離脱する。戦後ほどなく仏独の提携から始まり、東西冷戦の終結で欧州全域に広がった欧州統合の流れに生じた初の逆流である▲４年前の国民投票で離脱を決めた英国だが、ＥＵとの合意なき離脱も心配させたこの間のすったもんだである。総選挙に出たジョンソン政権の与党勝利でようやく離脱実現となったものの、離脱派と残留派で割れた世論の分断は続く▲今後はＥＵとの経済関係が維持される年末までの移行期間に入るが、その間に新たな自由貿易協定の合意ができねばまた大混乱の危機が訪れる。離脱派が夢見る「栄光ある孤立」を新たな成長の軌道に乗せるのは依然容易でなかろう▲グローバリズムへの草の根の反発により欧州統合の理想が足元から揺さぶられるＥＵも。。。」

What are they supposed to indicate? They seem to indicate breaks, but they probably don't mean the same thing as a comma or a period, which both also exist in the article.

Comment: Very regular positions: every third line in the middle.

Comment: Spaces, according to [this guide][1]. 

  [1]: https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%89%E8%A7%92_(%E8%A8%98%E5%8F%B7)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

段落（paragraph）の区切りです・・・

毎日新聞のコラム「余禄」では、▲
朝日新聞のコラム「天声人語」では、▼ を使って、
「ここで段落が変わる」ことを示しています。
（段落が変わるので本来は改行するところを、スペースが限られているため、代わりに記号で表している）

産経新聞のコラム「産経抄」は ▼ で、こんな感じです：

[image]

また、[このページ](https://stabucky.com/wp/archives/6979)によると、
読売新聞のコラム「編集手帳」では、◆ が使われているそうです。

Comment: そのような記号はいつからそのように使うようになったのだろうか

Comment: @Ringil さあ・・　どこが最初に始めたのかわかんないですけど、朝日新聞については、[ここ](http://info.asahi.com/guide/tenseijingo/history.html)によると、`天声人語が紙面に初めて登場したのは、日露戦争が始まる直前の１９０４(明治３７)年１月５日。記者として活躍した西村天囚（てんしゅう）が命名した。大阪で発行される紙面（大阪朝日）でのみ掲載が始まり、段落を区切る印は、現在の「▼」の逆の「▲」だった。` のだそうですよ。